# How to get or generate API key for Google rich snippets (ratings and reviews)?

Tags: google-rich-snippets

I need to implement and script with API key.

Did anyone know where I can get an API key for implementing rich snippets ratings and reviews?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any API key to create and enable rich snippets. Just follow the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews) and everything should be ok!

Answer (score 0):

this is the default Schema for each page on the website. You can ask someone to make a Python code for parsing data, to all of your pages. That parsing is like this:

**1. Copy the code below in all yout pages before**

**2. Make a python code that will:**

- retrieve data from `<title>` tag and put on schema below
- retrieve data from `<description>` tag and put on schema below
- retrieve data from `<canonical>` tag and put on schema below on URL
- change the path to `logo2.png` (also change logo)

**SCHEMA CODE for each html page:**

```
<!-- Schema Org Start -->

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://Your-Website.com/name-of-article.html"
  },
  "headline": NAME OF THE ARTICLE",
  "description": "PUT HERE THE DESCRIPTION OF YOUR ARTICLE.",
  "image": "https://Your-Website.com/icon-facebook.jpg",  
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "THE NAME OF THE WEBSITE",
    "url": "https://Your-Website.com/despre.html"
  },  
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "THE NAME OF THE WEBSITE",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://Your-Website.com/creative-studio/img/logo2.png"
    }
  },
  "datePublished": "2022-02-15",
  "dateModified": "2022-02-17"
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/", 
  "@type": "Product", 
  "name": NAME OF THE ARTICLE",
  "image": "https://Your-Website.com/icon-facebook.jpg",
  "description": "PUT HERE THE DESCRIPTION OF YOUR ARTICLE.",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Brand",
    "name": "THE NAME OF THE WEBSITE"
  },
  "sku": "NFL",
  "gtin8": "NFL",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://Your-Website.com/name-of-article.html",
    "priceCurrency": "RON",
    "price": "0",
    "priceValidUntil": "2022-02-15",
    "availability": "https://schema.org/OnlineOnly"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "5",
    "bestRating": "5",
    "ratingCount": "55"
  },
  "review": {
    "@type": "Review",
    "reviewRating": {
      "@type": "Rating",
      "ratingValue": "5",
      "bestRating": "5"
    },
    "author": {"@type": "Person", "name": "THE NAME OF THE WEBSITE"},
    "publisher": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "THE NAME OF THE WEBSITE"}
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Schema Org Final -->
```

Comment: spell check on the line: `1. Copy the code below in all yout pages before`

The line looks incomplete. Also maybe include a reference link as to why you need this running on each page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).